# ASP.NET login control connection string error : Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0, metadata, connection-string

I was working with normal connection until now and everything was smooth
but now I have switched to data entity model and with new connection string, I am having this error... How can i keep my entity string for my data manipulation and use the regular conn string only for login control?

```
Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +5055124
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +98
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +64
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +150
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value) +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +4
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +26
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder..ctor(String connectionString) +54

[ArgumentException: An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax.
Parameter name: connectionString]
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder..ctor(String connectionString) +136
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +119
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) +827
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +105
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +106
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +60
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +129
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +127
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +101
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +167
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

Connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LoginDB" connectionString="Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=int422_113b16;User ID=****;Password=****" />
    <add name="BlogEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.BlogModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.BlogModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.BlogModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source****;initial catalog=int422_113b16;user id=****;password=****;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: whats the code for your connectionstring ??

Comment: Try to place your connection string on App.config and WebConfig.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer...
Just thought about it rationally and checked the config file
All I had to do was change the connectionStringName for provider tag

Just for future reference if someone runs into same problem

Answer (score 0):

I was developing a custom user control and it still works flawless if I use the same in a test application but if I try to deploy the same, I get the same error and the following line of my custom control's code behind is highlighted in red in my browser :

```
SqlConnection CriminalConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
```

Err:

> Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.

Below are initial few lines of the stack trace:

> System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +5110852
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +98

**REASON**
In My case the connection string was not in correct format, for detailed explanation visit http://www.connectionstrings.com/